# How to add arbitrary executable programs to a Windows 7 Jump List?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, shortcuts, jumplist

In Windows 7, you can pin items to the taskbar.  Once an item is pinned to the taskbar, you can pin items to the list displayed when you right-click on it (known as a Jump List).

I have a pinned taskbar item that runs a script via `wscript.exe`.  When right-clicking on that pinned item, I want the list to show several other executable programs.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can with 3rd party programs, which is off topic here....https://www.technorms.com/5119/windows-7-jumplists-manager

Comment: @Moab Thanks... I'll read the link you posted.  Most appreciated.  Hopefully someone will have a tip to do this natively in Windows... if it's possible.

Comment: Not possible...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this natively in Windows.